# Removing the background from rounded corners

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP7rY.png

That's the problem, I'm tryin' but I can't remove that background-color from the rounded corners.

**HTML**

```
<div id="principal" align="center">
<header>
        <h1>
            <img src="images/pg_img.png" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pg_img_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pg_img.png'";>
        </h1>
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#principal {
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin:20px;
}
#principal header {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#principal header h1 {
    border:15px solid black;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
}
```

Well, above's the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that your background-color is on `#principal`, and your rounded corners are on `#principal header h1`

try this

delete this from `#principal`

```
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

and move it to `#principal header h1`

```
#principal header h1 {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See if this can help you.

Two way

```
#principal {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#principal header {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#principal header h1 {
    border:15px solid black;
}
```

Or

```
#principal {
    margin:20px;
}
#principal header {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#principal header h1 {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border:15px solid black;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
}
```